# How to use multi page mode in quasar?

Tags: quasar-framework, multi-page-application

Is it possible to have multi page mode in quasar?
In pure VueJS it's possible by configuring this option https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages.

In quasar I can't figure out whether this is possible as I can't find anything on this on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Create a new project using @vue/cli (Vue3)
> 2. Add as Quasar a plug in (
>    https://quasar.dev/start/vue-cli-plugin) - Enable Quasar tree-shaking
>    (recommended)
> 3. Configure Vue 3 to generate multiple pages using multi
>    page mode https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages
>
> This will generate a
> separate HTML page that references generated tree-shaken JS files for
> each entry point.

[Source](https://forum.quasar-framework.org/topic/1912/how-to-use-quasar-to-build-a-multi-page-application/6)

Answer (score 0):

I looked for a lot of places and didn't create multiple pages directly. My solution is to configure different environment variables to package multiple times and move `index.html`